# Is there a word, phrase, or expression that refers to a dying person by directly describing a physical state (e.g., weak breath)?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, expressions, idiom-request

In Chinese, we have the phrase "气若游丝" which, translated literally, means "breath being as weak as a wisp of silk" to describe a dying person.

The characteristics of this Chinese phrase are:

- It **directly** describes the weak breath of the person.
- It **indirectly** describes the dying state of the person.

In English, I can just say "The person is dying." I've also learned another phrase "on the verge of death". But both of them describe the dying state directly rather than use a physical state (e.g., the weak breath) of the person to describe the dying state.

I also saw a sentence in [this article](https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=12254393) that describes the breath which I think is a good one:

> I listened to his final breaths, **gasping and fish-like**, and I gripped his hand tight enough to feel the last pulsings of his heart.

**I'm just curious whether there are any other good ones similar to the example above because I guess not everyone's breath is "gasping and fish-like" when he/she is passing away.**

Comment: We have the idiomatic usage *[He's] [**on his last gasp***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+his+last+gasp&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20his%20last%20gasp%3B%2Cc0), which corresponds pretty closely to what you describe (he's ***dying***).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct parallel, a phrase which both describes the person's breathing and is recognized as an established idiom meaning the person is near death, but there are some relevant idioms around dying:

- People often reference one's "[last breath](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/last%2Fdying%20breath)," or "final" or "dying breath." Technically this refers to the very moment of death, but by extension one might say "he's on his last breath" to say that he is near death.
- Someone near death is said to be "[on their deathbed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deathbed)"

You could of course also describe the person's breathing in any way you want, as the quote does.